# Using a BAT file to automatically reconnect a VPN Cisco on failure of connection

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, cisco

I would like help to create an automatic BAT script that reconnects my Cisco VPN Client Session in case of outage of Internet.

There are two command lines: `command 1` to connect and `command 2` to disconnect.

To monitor the connection I would like use ICMP (Like `5 failed pings`) and if working VPN then continue to forward data. If not use `command 2` to disconnect the VPN Session and try to reconnect again.

If possible I would like it to loop so it will auto-reconnect every time the WAN Link breaks.

**command 1**: The Client program is at:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN`

```
start vpnclient connect rcx user TESTE pwd TESTE stdin
```

**command 2**: The Client program is at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN`

```
vpnclient disconnect
```

I made many attempts with no success.

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried? This will make it easier for people to help you to fix what is wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should ping the IP address and on failure it will disconnect, pause for 10 seconds, start the vpnclient and pause for 10 seconds, then loop.

There is a 30 second delay between tests.

The `timeout` command is in Vista and later.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN"
:loop
    echo testing IP address
    ping 123.456.78.90 >nul || (
       echo ping failure - disconnecting
       vpnclient disconnect
          timeout /t 10 /nobreak
       echo reconnecting
       start vpnclient connect rcx user TESTE pwd TESTE stdin
          timeout /t 10 /nobreak
   )
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Comment: Man, you are the guy!!!. Thank you soo much. I needed to adjust some parameters to work right in our environment, follow below:

Comment: Delete your comment - it has some info in it.

Comment: Foxdrive, one more question if you can answer, is there a way to start this sentence - ping 192.168.1.100 | FIND "TTL" >nul || ( ) - after 5 ping failed attempts?. Best Regards